# How to handle a nullable DateTime in a LINQ-to-SQL where condition?

Tags: linq-to-sql

I need to select a list of coupons that have not expired yet. That is:

```
where Coupon.ExpiresOn > DateTimeUtc.Now
```

Problem is that Coupon.ExpiresOn is a nullable of DateTime (DateTime?). The code above does not return coupons with null values in Coupon.ExpiresOn. How could I change it to return null values? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

allow nulls in your where, like so:

> where Coupon.ExpiresOn == null ||
>   Coupon.ExpiresOn > DateTimeUtc.Now

Answer (score 5):

Add an or to your where statement:

```
where !Coupon.ExpiresOn.HasValue || Coupon.ExpiresOn.Value > DateTimeUtc.Now
```

Comment: Actually, no.  Linq-to-SQL shortcircuits your C# shortcircuiting, so actually both sides of the statement get called.  Your answer still works correctly, but you have to be careful to remember that you're using Linq-to-SQL here (at least, the questioner is).  SQL Server doesn't shortcircuit, and it doesn't do case-sensitive compares, so you have to pay close attention to how your Linq is going to be used.

Comment: @matmc3 that's a very good point, I wasn't thinking it through.  I've updated my answer.  Thanks!